# get the descending order of cost by writing the name of senders in query

Tags: prolog

I need To give a  list of senders by making  Prolog rule to show if they are in descending order of their network charge for sending a message. If they are, return true, otherwise return false.

So,I have created below rule which showing me the number in descending order but lets suppose the numbers are the cost of the messages but I don't know how can I put list of senders according to their descending order of cost .

lets suppose `8,4,3,2` is the cost and by the below rule it showing me the correct descending order if i write query like this `:-?message([8,4,3,2])`.

```
message(8).
message(4).
message(3).
message(2).
```

The Rule i created for this data is

```
message([_]):-!.
message([_]):-!.
message([A,B|T]) :-A >= B,!,message([B|T]).
```

My original database look like this . Now my query will be like `:-?message([sonny,robert,fred,nayna]).`

This should return true as they are descending order in their cost.

```
%message(Sender, Receiver, Date, Cost_of_sending_a_message) 
message(sonny,robert,'2012-05-12',8).
message(robert,sarah,'2012-05-12',5).
message(julie,mary,'2012-05-12',6).
message(fred,nayna,'2012-05-13',6).
message(fred,daniel,'2012-05-14',6).
message(nayna,lucia,'2012-05-15',3).
```

Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong because I want to get the descending order of cost by writing the name of senders in query ?

Comment: @CommuSoft could you please give me hints ? I saw you answered so many questions regarding prolog .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order_by/2 from SWI-Prolog library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=order_by/2)) can help you:

example usage:

```
?- order_by([desc(C)], message(F,S,D,C)).
C = 8,
F = sonny,
S = robert,
D = '2012-05-12' ;
C = 6,
F = julie,
S = mary,
D = '2012-05-12'
...
```

*edit*:

```
?- findall(C, (order_by([desc(C)], message(F,S,D,C))), L).
```

Also library(aggregate), or the classical setof/3 offer possible solutions, but writing it by hand would be the better way to learn Prolog. It depends on what you're after...

Comment: This needs ';' to be entered to get each value. How can we get all values at once? Can we combine this with 'findall'?

Comment: It only produces L = [8, 6, 6, 6, 5, 3].. How can all records (F,S,D,C) be listed in order of C?

Comment: Please, seems so simple... try yourself. Experimenting **can** be fun, you know...

Comment: Thanks for not answering! I tried and was able to solve it. BTW, there is an extra '(' before order_by in your code:  findall(C, (order_by([desc(C)], message(F,S,D,C)), L).

Comment: Very well (and sorry for the typo, I didn't tested it) ! If you found my answer useful, I would like to see it marked as accepted. Anyway, thank you

Comment: @rnso i could not solve the problem .could you please give me a hints ?

Comment: findall((fred,S,D,C), (order_by([desc(C)], message(fred,S,D,C))), L).   works for getting entries of a particular person.

Comment: @rnso in my query, if I write the name of the sender in descending order (according to message cost) it will return true otherwise false .for example sender are arif,miraj and masum and their cost is 8,7,6. if I write the query ?(arif ,masum,miraj) it will retrun false as their cost is not descending order .it will return true only if i write ?(aruf,miraj,masum). I can get number in descending order but how can i get descending order writing only sender name .